# How to configure SonarQube using an aws cloud formation script?

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, sonarqube

I have a SonarQube installation in an existing Amazon AmiID. I now want to change a few lines in the SonarQube configuration dynamically during cloud formation.

How do I modify the `/opt/sonarqube/conf/sonar.properties` file using an aws cloud formation script?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you create an ec2 instance from the AMI.

You can add UserData property in the resource's property section and do your modification in there inform of a bash script.

```
"UserData":{  
   "Fn::Base64":{  
      "Fn::Join":[  
         "",
         [  
            "#!/bin/bash -v\n",
            "#Change Sonar Properties",
            "sed -i 'line_number/old_text/new_text/' /opt/sonarqube/conf/sonar.properties\n"
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```